# how do I manage one product with multiple vendors in magento?

Tags: php, mysql, magento-1.8

Suppose there are multiple vendors for the same product (say a mobile phone of a xyz brand/model) .

One product but multiple vendors.

Is it possible to list all the vendors on the product page for that particular product?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple vendors can add same product but you should take care of SKU is not similar.

For Example

```
Vendor A has Mobile phone of XYZ model.

Vendor B also has Mobile phone of XYZ model

The only thing is SKU is differ for both the products
```

Comment: but in this way on category page every vendor's product will repeat so my query is to show one product with different vendor name and price like http://www.snapdeal.com/viewAllSellers/product/zotac-nvidia-geforce-gtx-970/1351360951 here product is one but two sellers. i want same like this is there any solutions in magento...@Charlie